# How to get total gross avenue for current month in the woocommerce dashboard status widget

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to show gross sales for the current month in woocommerce status widget in admin dashboard. Currently it shows net sales amount I need to change to gross sales amount

Comment: Please consider posting this on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ecg8 posted. Thanks

Comment: Wordpress StackExchange is just for pure Wordpress questions (no plugins related)… As this question is related to Woocommerce, StackOverFlow is the right place…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec cool